# scheduled job problem with Parameterized Scheduler Plugin

Tags: jenkins

I need to schedule a job with parameters with the Parameterized Scheduler plugin which runs every day at 1pm I try to plan it but without success I have not found the correct cron

13 * * * * % Environment=DV46
13 * * * * % Environment=MT22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) you have a documentation for cron.

So if you wand to start your Job every Day at 13:00 you have to use:

`0 13 * * *`

But there seems to be a limitation. When you define it like

```
0 13 * * * % Environment=DV46
0 13 * * * % Environment=MT22
```

only the first one will be executed.

So i recommend you start the second one at 13:01:

```
0 13 * * * % Environment=DV46
1 13 * * * % Environment=MT22
```